# Broken rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I got to something strange today that totally puzzled me what is wrong.
This piece of code doesn't render well in my FF 40.0.3 on my MBP but without any problems in Chrome and Safari.

https://jsfiddle.net/j07vrjv1/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
        <td>
            <button style="width: 100%">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can someone point me why the button is shorter than its label?

[image: Wrong rendering]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set the width 100% in `td`.

You need to set the width of td instead `button`.

```html
<br/>
<br/>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid red">100% ?</td>
        <td style="border:1px solid red">
            <button style="width:100%;border:1px solid red">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, this snippet was just to show the wrong rendering. In my real case I need one column to occupy the whole width while all other columns width is just enough for the content. In the real case the button column was just 8 pixels wide which is just not acceptable. And this behaviour is only in FF.

Comment: Is it possible to set the width of first td 90% and the other one 10%. ?

Comment: I'm not looking for workaround for that. I'm looking to understand why this piece of simple HTML renders in a different way in FF and other browsers. Then with that knowledge will decide how to fix it.